# Unable to pass data through Express Middleware locals

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I am attempting to pass data from a middleware controller method to the view, however when attempting to access res.locals in my get method, it returns empty. When logging the array from the controller method, it is filled, but the array seems to clear when attempting to access it in the get request.

the snippet below skips the logic of filling the array and uses arbitrary values for resArray. I would like to access res.locals in server.js

controller.js

```
function createTable(req, res, next){
                let resArray = [8, 9, 10];
                req.resArray = resArray; //sending array to locals
                console.log(req.resArray);
                res.locals.resArray = resArray;
                console.log("LOCALS FROM CONTROLLER: ", res.locals); //Logs [8, 9, 10]
                next();
}
```

server.js

```
app.get('/', createTable, (req, res) => {
    console.log("LOCALS: ", res.locals); //Logs empty object
    res.render("index");
    
});
```

body from index.ejs

```
<form action="./" method="get" id="form">
    <!-- endpoint of API to be selected -->
    <select name="endpoint">
        <option value="albums">Albums</option>>
        <option value="posts">Posts</option>
        <option value="todos">Todos</option>
    </select>
    <select name="order">
        <option value="first">First</option>
        <option value="last">Last</option>
    </select>
        Count: <input type="number" name="count" placeholder="1" /> <br>
        UserId: <select name="userIdSelected">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You're not calling `next()` therefore your middleware acts like a controller and stops passing the control flow to any other middlewares/controllers after it

Comment: I forgot to include ```next()```  in the post, but it is in my code and still not passing.